# @WithMockUser ignores username, password fields?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm using `@WithMockUser` to test a controller method secured with basic auth in a simple spring boot web service.  My annotation looks like:

```
@WithMockUser(username = 'admin', password = 'mypassword', roles = ['ADMIN'])
```

It seems however that the username and password field are ignored. The test passes even if I specify an incorrect username or password.  The roles field however does appear to be used and the test fails with an invalid role is provided.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the role of this annotation, but should I be able to use it to verify behavior of incorrect credentials being supplied to a secured method?

Thanks!

--john

Comment: No you shouldn't. What it does it repopulates the `SecurityContext` with the given user. It doesn't allow you to test anything else. If you want that, you need to do a system test or full integration test using Springs Mock MVC test support including manually registering your Security configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *Spring MVC Test* (i.e., `MockMvc`), you would do something like the following:

```java
mvc.perform(get("/").with(httpBasic("user","password"))) // ...
```

This is documented in the [Testing HTTP Basic Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#testing-http-basic-authentication) section of the Spring Security reference manual.

If you have configured your test to launch Spring Boot with an embedded Servlet container, you can use Spring Boot's [TestRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-rest-templates-test-utility) which supports "Basic HTTP authentication (with a username and password)".

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. I think @WithMockUser is enough to test secured services. user/password/roles is not required. I validated this scenario in my case.

Comment: Please don't answer with assumptions